# Why is my bootstrap navbar not dropping down?

Tags: html, css, navbar

Why is my toggle menu not dropping down has a solid black box? It just drops down in the center transparent. How do I fix it so it will drop down as a solid block and positioned left? I am using a bootstrap navbar and I edited it with external CSS. I tried to find out how to fix it but I am having trouble finding an answer. I'm very new to HTML, CSS, and Javascript, I'm not sure if I am even explaining the problem accurately enough to get a google answer. Hopefully, someone here knows what I mean, thanks.
My CSS:

```
 .navbar {
     background-color: black;
     height: 15%;
     line-height: 280px;
}
 li {
     padding-right: 10px;
     padding-left: 10px;
}
 .collapse {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     text-align: center;
}
 .nav-link {
     color: white !important;
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 120%;
     font-style: italic 
}
 .poetry-monkey-logo-center {
     height: 15px;
}
 .poetry-monkey-logo-center>img {
     height: 120px;
     width: 130px;
     border: 10px solid black;
     border-radius: 80%;
     margin-top: 40px;
}
/* .navbar-brand {
     border:5px solid black;
     border-radius: 80%;
     margin-top:80px;
     background-color: white;
     height: 59%;
}
 nav {
     width:100%;
     height: 15%;
     list-style:none;
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 130%;
     display:inline;
     text-align:center;
     background-color: black;
     border-bottom: 15px solid black;
}
 .nav-link {
     color: white !important;
     text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #ffaf1a;
}
 #navbar-nav {
     position:fixed;
}
 div ul {
     line-height: 390px 
}
 div ul li {
     width: 1%;
     margin-left: 190px;
}
 li {
     margin-right: -80px;
}
 .nav-item-logo {
     width:30%;
     margin-right: -190px;
}
 .nav-link {
     margin-top:350%;
}
*/
 .navbar-toggler {
     background-color: white;
}
 body {
     background-color: white;
}
 .container {
     color: black;
     margin-top: 200px !important;
     min-height: 250px !important;
}
 .jumbotron {
     background-image: url("rainbow-stripes-jumbotron-background.jpg");
     background-color: #e6e6e6;
     background-size: 100% 100%;
     margin-top: 6%;
     border-bottom: 6px solid black;
    /*padding-top: 1%;
     padding-bottom: 1%;
     height: 492px !important;
    */
}
 #jumbotron-h1 {
     font-size: 480%;
     font-weight: bold;
     text-align: center;
     color: white;
     text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px black;
}
 #jumbotron-p {
     font-size: 280%;
     font-weight: bold;
     text-align: center;
     color: white;
     text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px black;
}
 #angels-and-demons {
     border: 1px solid gray;
     border-radius: 4px;
     padding: 5px;
     width: 285px;
     height: 250px;
}
 #the-earth-from-space {
     border: 1px solid gray;
     border-radius: 4px;
     padding: 5px;
     width: 285px;
     height: 250px;
}
 #great-teacher {
     border: 1px solid gray;
     border-radius: 4px;
     padding: 5px;
     width: 285px;
     height: 250px;
}
 #poem-a, #poem-b, #poem-c {
     display: none;
}
 .poem-1, .poem-2, .poem-3 {
     margin: auto;
     width: 50%;
     text-align: center;
     font-style: italic;
     padding: 10px;
     padding-bottom: 100px;
     border-bottom: 2px solid currentColor;
     color: black;
     font-weight: 400;
}
 #p-poem {
     display: none;
}
 .p-title {
     text-decoration: underlie;
     font-size: 250%;
     font-weight: 100 !important;
     text-align: center;
}
/*footer starts*/
 .footer-bs {
     background-color: #3c3d41;
     padding: 60px 40px;
     color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00);
     margin-bottom: 20px;
     border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
     border-top-left-radius: 0px;
     border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
}
 .footer-bs .footer-brand, .footer-bs .footer-nav, .footer-bs .footer-social, .footer-bs .footer-ns {
     padding: 10px 25px;
}
 .footer-bs .footer-nav, .footer-bs .footer-social, .footer-bs .footer-ns {
     border-color: transparent;
}
 .footer-bs .footer-brand h2 {
     margin: 0px 0px 10px;
}
 .footer-bs .footer-brand p {
     font-size: 12px;
     color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.70);
}
 .footer-bs .footer-nav ul.pages {
     list-style: none;
     padding: 0px;
}
 .footer-bs .footer-nav ul.pages li {
     padding: 5px 0px;
}
 .footer-bs .footer-nav ul.pages a {
     color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00);
     font-weight: bold;
     text-transform: uppercase;
}
 .footer-bs .footer-nav ul.pages a:hover {
     color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.80);
     text-decoration: none;
}
 .footer-bs .footer-nav h4 {
     font-size: 11px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     letter-spacing: 3px;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
}
 .footer-bs .footer-nav ul.list {
     list-style: none;
     padding: 0px;
}
 .footer-bs .footer-nav ul.list li {
     padding: 5px 0px;
}
 .footer-bs .footer-nav ul.list a {
     color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.80);
}
 .footer-bs .footer-nav ul.list a:hover {
     color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.60);
     text-decoration: none;
}
 .footer-bs .footer-social ul {
     list-style: none;
     padding: 0px;
}
 .footer-bs .footer-social h4 {
     font-size: 11px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     letter-spacing: 3px;
}
 .footer-bs .footer-social li {
     padding: 5px 4px;
}
 .footer-bs .footer-social a {
     color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00);
}
 .footer-bs .footer-social a:hover {
     color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.80);
     text-decoration: none;
}
 .footer-bs .footer-ns h4 {
     font-size: 11px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     letter-spacing: 3px;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
}
 .footer-bs .footer-ns p {
     font-size: 12px;
     color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.70);
}
 @media (min-width: 768px) {
     .footer-bs .footer-nav, .footer-bs .footer-social, .footer-bs .footer-ns {
         border-left: solid 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.10);
    }
}
/*footer ends*/
```

My HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <title> PoetryMonkey.com</title>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
         
             $("#button-a").click(function(){
             $("#a-poem").hide("slow");
             });
         
             $("#button-b").click(function(){
             $("#a-poem").show("slow");
             
             });
         
             $("#button-c").click(function(){
               $("#b-poem").hide();
             });
         
             $("#button-d").click(function(){
               $("#b-poem").show();
             });
         
             $("#button-e").click(function(){
               $("#c-poem").hide();
             });
         
             $("#button-f").click(function(){
               $("#c-poem").show();
             });
         
         });
      </script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="assignment-5.css" type="text/css" media="all">
   </head>
   <body>
      <!-- Navbar start -->
      <nav class="navbar fixed-top  navbar-expand-sm navbar-light p-3 mb-2" >
         <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
         <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
         </button>
         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse "  id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
               <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
               </li>
               <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
               </li>
               <li class="nav-item-logo">
                  <a class="poetry-monkey-logo-center"  href="#"><img src="final-poetry-monkey-logo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Logo, a thinking monkey with glasses on"></a>
               </li>
               <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
               </li>
               <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </nav>
      <!--start of jumbotron-->
      <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
         <div id="jumbotron-text" class="d-flex flex-column mb-3 flex-fill justify-content-center">
            <div class="div-1">
               <h1 id ="jumbotron-h1" class="display-4"> Welcome To The Poetry Monkey!
               </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="div-2">
               <p id="jumbotron-p" class="lead">A place where writers can share poetry and view poetry.</p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!--end of jumbotron-->
      <br><br><br>
      <div class="poem-1">
         <img id="angels-and-demons" src="angels-and-demons-poem.png" alt="red firer engery clashing with blue icey energy">
         <p class="p-title">Angels And Demons</p>
         <p>
            One has a homeup high above and a quiet hand that heals. The other lives deep below in a hot shadowy hole and has the darkest of snaky hands that steels.
         </p>
         <p id="a-poem">They are immoratl foes fighting for mans soul. For thousands of years they've battled again and again. The beast from below craws up into the light. From heaven the golden guardian of good swiftly descends. Once more there will be a clash of thunderous might.
         </p>
         <button id="button-b" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</button>
         <button id="button-a" type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Read Less</button>
      </div>
      <br><br><br>
      <div class="poem-2">
         <img id="the-earth-from-space" src="the-earth-from-space-poem.png" alt="earth view from space">
         <p class="p-title">The Earth From Space</p>
         <p>
            Up above the clouds past the night sky.
            With wide eyes gazing down it becomes so clear. I see the truth away from and above the flock up high.
         </p>
         <p id="b-poem">I see plainly as if I had looked in a miror. We are one as the ocean is whole. And seperation fixes the chains upon us but collaboration gives us the key. One big flow of body abd soul. up above so high the truth I can see.
         </p>
         <button id="button-d" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</button>
         <button id="button-c" type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Read Less</button>
      </div>
      <br><br><br>
      <div class="poem-3">
         <img id="great-teacher" src="great-teacher-poem.png" alt="jesus">
         <p class="p-title">Great Teacher</p>
         <p>
            His wisdom was rooted deep down at the begining of time inside love and outside fear. Before the trees grew tall, man loved and died, or the clouds were spread across the skys.
         </p>
         <p id="c-poem">His heart bloomed pure as the crytal is clear. He gave us beauty inside and to the beauty outside he opened our eyes. The seeds of his teachings produced a wholesome love. He called for all wars to cease.
            Gone from this world now in the glorious palace high above. Shinning bright white he is the prince of peace.
         </p>
         <button id="button-f" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</button>
         <button id="button-e" type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Read Less</button>
      </div>
      <!--footer starts-->
      <div class="container">
         <section style="height:80px;"></section>
         <div class="row" style="text-align:center;">
            <h2>ThePoetryMonkey.com</h2>
         </div>
         <!----------- Footer ------------>
         <footer class="footer-bs">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-3 footer-brand animated fadeInLeft">
                  <h2>Lorem</h2>
                  <p>Suspendisse hendrerit tellus laoreet luctus pharetra. Aliquam porttitor vitae orci nec ultricies. Curabitur vehicula, libero eget faucibus faucibus, purus erat eleifend enim, porta pellentesque ex mi ut sem.</p>
                  <p>© 2020 All rights reserved</p>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-4 footer-nav animated fadeInUp">
                  <h4>Menu —</h4>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                     <ul class="pages">
                        <li><a href="#">Travel</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Nature</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Explores</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Science</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Advice</a></li>
                     </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                     <ul class="list">
                        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Terms & Condition</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                     </ul>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-2 footer-social animated fadeInDown">
                  <h4>Follow Us</h4>
                  <ul>
                     <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">RSS</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-3 footer-ns animated fadeInRight">
                  <h4>Newsletter</h4>
                  <p>Ducks flying north don't wake up the farmer</p>
                  <p>
                  <div class="input-group">
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
                     <span class="input-group-btn">
                     <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></button>
                     </span>
                  </div>
                  <!-- /input-group -->
               </div>
            </div>
         </footer>
         <section style="text-align:center; margin:10px auto;">
            <p>Designed by <a href="http://enfoplus.net">Joseph Minty </a></p>
         </section>
      </div>
      <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
      <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   </body>
</html>
<!-- end snippet -->
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense why you have added additional CSS to class `collapse`, it was causing everything in the center and add some media queries to see those navigation links and remove line-height that is also too much.

```css
.navbar {
     background-color: black;
     height: 15%;
     line-height: 280px;
}
 li {
     padding-right: 10px;
     padding-left: 10px;
}

 .nav-link {
     color: white !important;
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 120%;
     font-style: italic 
}
 .poetry-monkey-logo-center {
     height: 15px;
}
 .poetry-monkey-logo-center>img {
     height: 120px;
     width: 130px;
     border: 10px solid black;
     border-radius: 80%;
     margin-top: 40px;
}
/* .navbar-brand {
     border:5px solid black;
     border-radius: 80%;
     margin-top:80px;
     background-color: white;
     height: 59%;
}
 nav {
     width:100%;
     height: 15%;
     list-style:none;
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 130%;
     display:inline;
     text-align:center;
     background-color: black;
     border-bottom: 15px solid black;
}
 .nav-link {
     color: white !important;
     text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #ffaf1a;
}
 #navbar-nav {
     position:fixed;
}
 div ul {
     line-height: 390px 
}
 div ul li {
     width: 1%;
     margin-left: 190px;
}
 li {
     margin-right: -80px;
}
 .nav-item-logo {
     width:30%;
     margin-right: -190px;
}
 .nav-link {
     margin-top:350%;
}
*/
 .navbar-toggler {
     background-color: white;
}
 body {
     background-color: white;
}
 .container {
     color: black;
     margin-top: 200px !important;
     min-height: 250px !important;
}
 .jumbotron {
     background-image: url("rainbow-stripes-jumbotron-background.jpg");
     background-color: #e6e6e6;
     background-size: 100% 100%;
     margin-top: 6%;
     border-bottom: 6px solid black;
    /*padding-top: 1%;
     padding-bottom: 1%;
     height: 492px !important;
    */
}
 #jumbotron-h1 {
     font-size: 480%;
     font-weight: bold;
     text-align: center;
     color: white;
     text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px black;
}
 #jumbotron-p {
     font-size: 280%;
     font-weight: bold;
     text-align: center;
     color: white;
     text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px black;
}
 #angels-and-demons {
     border: 1px solid gray;
     border-radius: 4px;
     padding: 5px;
     width: 285px;
     height: 250px;
}
 #the-earth-from-space {
     border: 1px solid gray;
     border-radius: 4px;
     padding: 5px;
     width: 285px;
     height: 250px;
}
 #great-teacher {
     border: 1px solid gray;
     border-radius: 4px;
     padding: 5px;
     width: 285px;
     height: 250px;
}
 #poem-a, #poem-b, #poem-c {
     display: none;
}
 .poem-1, .poem-2, .poem-3 {
     margin: auto;
     width: 50%;
     text-align: center;
     font-style: italic;
     padding: 10px;
     padding-bottom: 100px;
     border-bottom: 2px solid currentColor;
     color: black;
     font-weight: 400;
}
 #p-poem {
     display: none;
}
 .p-title {
     text-decoration: underlie;
     font-size: 250%;
     font-weight: 100 !important;
     text-align: center;
}
/*footer starts*/
 .footer-bs {
     background-color: #3c3d41;
     padding: 60px 40px;
     color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00);
     margin-bottom: 20px;
     border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
     border-top-left-radius: 0px;
     border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
}
 .footer-bs .footer-brand, .footer-bs .footer-nav, .footer-bs .footer-social, .footer-bs .footer-ns {
     padding: 10px 25px;
}
 .footer-bs .footer-nav, .footer-bs .footer-social, .footer-bs .footer-ns {
     border-color: transparent;
}
 .footer-bs .footer-brand h2 {
     margin: 0px 0px 10px;
}
 .footer-bs .footer-brand p {
     font-size: 12px;
     color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.70);
}
 .footer-bs .footer-nav ul.pages {
     list-style: none;
     padding: 0px;
}
 .footer-bs .footer-nav ul.pages li {
     padding: 5px 0px;
}
 .footer-bs .footer-nav ul.pages a {
     color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00);
     font-weight: bold;
     text-transform: uppercase;
}
 .footer-bs .footer-nav ul.pages a:hover {
     color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.80);
     text-decoration: none;
}
 .footer-bs .footer-nav h4 {
     font-size: 11px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     letter-spacing: 3px;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
}
 .footer-bs .footer-nav ul.list {
     list-style: none;
     padding: 0px;
}
 .footer-bs .footer-nav ul.list li {
     padding: 5px 0px;
}
 .footer-bs .footer-nav ul.list a {
     color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.80);
}
 .footer-bs .footer-nav ul.list a:hover {
     color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.60);
     text-decoration: none;
}
 .footer-bs .footer-social ul {
     list-style: none;
     padding: 0px;
}
 .footer-bs .footer-social h4 {
     font-size: 11px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     letter-spacing: 3px;
}
 .footer-bs .footer-social li {
     padding: 5px 4px;
}
 .footer-bs .footer-social a {
     color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00);
}
 .footer-bs .footer-social a:hover {
     color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.80);
     text-decoration: none;
}
 .footer-bs .footer-ns h4 {
     font-size: 11px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     letter-spacing: 3px;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
}
 .footer-bs .footer-ns p {
     font-size: 12px;
     color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.70);
}
 @media (min-width: 768px) {
     .footer-bs .footer-nav, .footer-bs .footer-social, .footer-bs .footer-ns {
         border-left: solid 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.10);
    }
}
/*footer ends*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <title> PoetryMonkey.com</title>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
         
             $("#button-a").click(function(){
             $("#a-poem").hide("slow");
             });
         
             $("#button-b").click(function(){
             $("#a-poem").show("slow");
             
             });
         
             $("#button-c").click(function(){
               $("#b-poem").hide();
             });
         
             $("#button-d").click(function(){
               $("#b-poem").show();
             });
         
             $("#button-e").click(function(){
               $("#c-poem").hide();
             });
         
             $("#button-f").click(function(){
               $("#c-poem").show();
             });
         
         });
      </script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="assignment-5.css" type="text/css" media="all">
   </head>
   <body>
      <!-- Navbar start -->
      <nav class="navbar fixed-top  navbar-expand-sm navbar-light p-3 mb-2" >
         <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
         <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
         </button>
         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse "  id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
               <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
               </li>
               <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
               </li>
               <li class="nav-item-logo">
                  <a class="poetry-monkey-logo-center"  href="#"><img src="final-poetry-monkey-logo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Logo, a thinking monkey with glasses on"></a>
               </li>
               <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
               </li>
               <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </nav>
      <!--start of jumbotron-->
      <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
         <div id="jumbotron-text" class="d-flex flex-column mb-3 flex-fill justify-content-center">
            <div class="div-1">
               <h1 id ="jumbotron-h1" class="display-4"> Welcome To The Poetry Monkey!
               </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="div-2">
               <p id="jumbotron-p" class="lead">A place where writers can share poetry and view poetry.</p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!--end of jumbotron-->
      <br><br><br>
      <div class="poem-1">
         <img id="angels-and-demons" src="angels-and-demons-poem.png" alt="red firer engery clashing with blue icey energy">
         <p class="p-title">Angels And Demons</p>
         <p>
            One has a homeup high above and a quiet hand that heals. The other lives deep below in a hot shadowy hole and has the darkest of snaky hands that steels.
         </p>
         <p id="a-poem">They are immoratl foes fighting for mans soul. For thousands of years they've battled again and again. The beast from below craws up into the light. From heaven the golden guardian of good swiftly descends. Once more there will be a clash of thunderous might.
         </p>
         <button id="button-b" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</button>
         <button id="button-a" type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Read Less</button>
      </div>
      <br><br><br>
      <div class="poem-2">
         <img id="the-earth-from-space" src="the-earth-from-space-poem.png" alt="earth view from space">
         <p class="p-title">The Earth From Space</p>
         <p>
            Up above the clouds past the night sky.
            With wide eyes gazing down it becomes so clear. I see the truth away from and above the flock up high.
         </p>
         <p id="b-poem">I see plainly as if I had looked in a miror. We are one as the ocean is whole. And seperation fixes the chains upon us but collaboration gives us the key. One big flow of body abd soul. up above so high the truth I can see.
         </p>
         <button id="button-d" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</button>
         <button id="button-c" type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Read Less</button>
      </div>
      <br><br><br>
      <div class="poem-3">
         <img id="great-teacher" src="great-teacher-poem.png" alt="jesus">
         <p class="p-title">Great Teacher</p>
         <p>
            His wisdom was rooted deep down at the begining of time inside love and outside fear. Before the trees grew tall, man loved and died, or the clouds were spread across the skys.
         </p>
         <p id="c-poem">His heart bloomed pure as the crytal is clear. He gave us beauty inside and to the beauty outside he opened our eyes. The seeds of his teachings produced a wholesome love. He called for all wars to cease.
            Gone from this world now in the glorious palace high above. Shinning bright white he is the prince of peace.
         </p>
         <button id="button-f" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</button>
         <button id="button-e" type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Read Less</button>
      </div>
      <!--footer starts-->
      <div class="container">
         <section style="height:80px;"></section>
         <div class="row" style="text-align:center;">
            <h2>ThePoetryMonkey.com</h2>
         </div>
         <!----------- Footer ------------>
         <footer class="footer-bs">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-3 footer-brand animated fadeInLeft">
                  <h2>Lorem</h2>
                  <p>Suspendisse hendrerit tellus laoreet luctus pharetra. Aliquam porttitor vitae orci nec ultricies. Curabitur vehicula, libero eget faucibus faucibus, purus erat eleifend enim, porta pellentesque ex mi ut sem.</p>
                  <p>© 2020 All rights reserved</p>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-4 footer-nav animated fadeInUp">
                  <h4>Menu —</h4>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                     <ul class="pages">
                        <li><a href="#">Travel</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Nature</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Explores</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Science</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Advice</a></li>
                     </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                     <ul class="list">
                        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Terms & Condition</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                     </ul>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-2 footer-social animated fadeInDown">
                  <h4>Follow Us</h4>
                  <ul>
                     <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">RSS</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-3 footer-ns animated fadeInRight">
                  <h4>Newsletter</h4>
                  <p>Ducks flying north don't wake up the farmer</p>
                  <p>
                  <div class="input-group">
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
                     <span class="input-group-btn">
                     <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></button>
                     </span>
                  </div>
                  <!-- /input-group -->
               </div>
            </div>
         </footer>
         <section style="text-align:center; margin:10px auto;">
            <p>Designed by <a href="http://enfoplus.net">Joseph Minty </a></p>
         </section>
      </div>
      <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
      <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```